# Python : Check for filename ending with an extension present in a list of extensions

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically **I want the filenames ending with an extension present in the list of extensions**.
Here is my code in python.
I have taken some sample filenames as a list as given below:

```
extensions = ['.mp3','.m4a','.wma']
filenames = ['foo1.mp3','foo2.txt','foo3.m4a','foo4.mp4']
for filename in filenames:
    for extension in extensions:
         if filename.endswith(extension):
             print filename
             break
```

This is working but I am curious to know whether there's a more efficient or short way of doing the same thing in python.
Thank you

Comment: `for filename in filenames: if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions): print filename`?

Comment: as for effeciency... it's hard to tell because your description says you want the filenames (plural), but your code only prints out the first one - which is the actual desired behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 's comment is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @scytale: Huh? The `break` only breaks the inner loop. Two filenames are printed by the above code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`endswith` accepts a tuple, so it's very easy:

```
exts = tuple(extensions)
[f for f in filenames if f.endswith(exts)]
```

Comment: Did not know that. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
print [f for f in filenames if f[f.rindex('.'):] in extensions]
```

How it works:

It's a list comprehension, so the interesting part is after the "if".

Well, we use f.rindex('.') to find the last dot in the filename. Then we use slicing to get the part of f from there to the end. And finally, "in extensions" simply checks if the extensions list contains the file's extension.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for a concise way to do this:

```
[f for f in filenames for e in extensions if f.endswith(e)]
```

Comment: This doesn't short-cut, so will be less efficient.

Comment: poster asked for more effecient OR short

Comment: That's true, but given that you can easily do both why settle for one (you could at least *mention* this property)?